# Schedule heterogeneous tasks on heterogeneous machines

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, job-scheduling, scheduled-tasks

We have n jobs and m machines. Each job i has a release time r[i]. Processing job i on machine j takes p[i][j] time. For one job k, |{p[i][j] | i == k}| <= c, where c << m. We define the delay of job i as f[i] - r[i], where f[i] is the time when job i is finished. The system is not preemptive, i.e., when one job is started on some machine, it cannot be interrupted before it finishes. The goal is to provide a scheduling algorithm that minimizes the delay sum of all jobs. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reduction from the [3-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem).

Let S = {x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>3m</sub>} be the instance of 3-partition such that, for every i, B/4 < x<sub>i</sub> < B/2, where B = ∑x<sub>i</sub>/m is the target sum.

Let there be m *identical* machines. At time 0, release 3m jobs of lengths x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>3m</sub>. At each time B, B + 1, …, B + 4mB - 1, release m jobs of length 1, for a total of 4m<sup>2</sup>B jobs.

The instance of 3-partition has a solution if and only if the makespan of the initial jobs is less than or equal to B. If there is a solution, then the contribution of the initial jobs to the objective is at most 3mB. The contribution of the other jobs is 4m<sup>2</sup>B.

If the makespan is longer than B, then a chain of 4mB jobs is delayed at least one unit, contributing 4mB to the objective. Thus the objective is at most 3mB + 4m<sup>2</sup>B if the 3-partition problem is solvable and at least 4mB + 4m<sup>2</sup>B if the 3-partition problem is not solvable.

Comment: Hi Per. Thank you very much for your reply, and sorry for the delay. But I am not very clear about the reduction. You said "At times B, B + 1, …, B + 4mB - 1, release m jobs of length 1." But there are "4mB - 1" different time instance. Would you please clear this up?

Comment: @Geni Edited. I wanted a full schedule from time B onward.

Comment: Hi Per. If the scheduling problem is NP-hard, is there any approximation algorithm that we can use? Thanks!